# how to read a variable line by line from a text file and split it python

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm trying to create a sign up menu where it takes your username and password then saves them onto a new line in a text text file so after making multiple accounts ill have multiple lines with one username and one password each. i then want to read the file back line by line and split the username and password into two variables (u and p), save u and p onto a database in sqlite3 then repeat for the next line until all lines have been saved to the database. however i cannot figure this out as no matter what i try there's an error with unpacking values either to many or to few. i think the \n at the end of each line may be the/one of the problems.
any help is appreciated thanks.
Here is the code:

```
import time
import sqlite3
import os


db2 = sqlite3.connect('pass.db')
cur = db2.cursor()

def sign_up():
    global cur

    details = '1'

    with open('username','a') as user:

        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pass (username TEXT, password TEXT)')

        username = input('please enter a username:')
        username = username.title()


        password = ''
        password2 = '.'

        while password != password2 or len(password) < 6 or password.isalnum() == False:
            password = input('please enter a password with AT LEAST 6 CHARACTERS AND ONE NUMBER:')
            password2 = input('please confirm your password:')
        user.write(username + ',' + password + ',' + '\n')



    with open('username','r') as user:
        hello = ''.join(user.readlines())
        print (hello)

        for line in hello:
            details = user.readline()
            details = ''.join(details)
            print (details)
            u, p = details.split(',')
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO pass (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)',(u, p,)) 
        print(u)
        print(p)

    cur.execute('SELECT username FROM pass WHERE username = ?',(username,))
    for row in cur:
        print(row)

sign_up()
```

Comment: what if there is a comma in either the user and password?

Comment: This is a terrible way to handle passwords. You should never, ever store a plaintext password. At the very least, you should hash it with a salt before storing. There are many references for this and better design approaches -- invest 5 minutes in a Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `details = ''.join(details)` code with follwing

```
details = details.strip()
if details != '':
    u, p = details.split(',')            
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO pass (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)',(u., p,))
```

use strip() or lstrip() function which will remove '\n'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are joining the lines in `hello`. When you iterate, you are iterating the characters in a string, and of course you cannnot split a character.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys i know this is by no means the best way to store passwords or anything but for what its used for and i have looked on google to try and find something better but everything that came up was either far to basic or at a level i dont yet understand and the actual security of the password isnt too important for what im using them for.

i got it too work with this code:

```
import time
```

import sqlite3
import os

db2 = sqlite3.connect('pass.db')
cur = db2.cursor()

def sign_up():
    global cur

```
details = '1'

with open('username','a') as user:

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pass (username TEXT, password TEXT)')

    username = input('please enter a username:')
    username = username.title()


    password = ''
    password2 = '.'

    while password != password2 or len(password) < 6 or password.isalnum() == False:
        password = input('please enter a password with AT LEAST 6 CHARACTERS AND ONE NUMBER:')
        password2 = input('please confirm your password:')
    user.write(username + ',' + password + ',' + '\n')



with open('username','r') as user:

    details = user.readline()
    details = details.strip()
    print(details)
    while details !=  '':
        if details != '':
            u, p = details.split(',',1)            
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO pass (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)',(u, p,))
            details = user.readline()
            details = details.strip()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM pass')
for row in cur:
    print(row)
cur.execute('SELECT username FROM pass WHERE username = ?',(username,))
data = cur.fetchall()
if len(data) == 0:
    sign_up()
```

sign_up()